# What would "I Discover" be in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, word-request, word-choice

I need the Latin for "I Discover" - as in "I learn new things, by gathering information about it and/or trying it myself (by trial and error)".

I've looked for it in several online dictionaries, but several different suggestions shows, and I don't know which one would fit the best.  Nor am I entirely sure which ending to give the verb for "**I** discover"...  Finally, perhaps there is another verb that better fits what I'm describing, than any of the ones suggested.

I got pretty much more or less the same from all dictionaries I tred, I'll here quote for the one at Notre Dame, since it had such dense format:

```
reperio, reperire, repperi, repertus  V  TRANS     3 4  TRANS   [XXXAO]  
discover, learn; light on; find/obtain/get; find out/to be, get to know; invent;

conperio, conperire, conperi, conpertus  V  TRANS     3 4  TRANS   [XXXAO]  
learn/discover/find (by investigation); verify/know for certain; find guilty;

comperio, comperire, comperi, compertus  V  TRANS     3 4  TRANS   [XXXAO]  
learn/discover/find (by investigation); verify/know for certain; find guilty;

repperio, repperire, repperi, reppertus  V  TRANS     3 4  TRANS   [XXXAO]  
discover, learn; light on; find/obtain/get; find out/to be, get to know; invent;

invenio, invenire, inveni, inventus  V     3 4 [XXXAX]  
come upon; discover, find; invent, contrive; reach, manage to get;

profero, proferre, protuli, prolatus  V     3 2 [XXXAX]  
bring forward; advance; defer; discover; mention;
```

First off, what is the difference between "co**n**perio" and "co**m**perio"?

Anyway, I guess I'd want one with "learn"... but since I'll be gathering information and learn by trying myself, I suppose I'd want one of them including "by investigation" - ie. conperio/comperio...?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Conperio* and *comperio* are just variant spellings, and the same with *reperio* and *repperio*. The "normal" words though are *comperio* and *reperio*.

That said, the word I've come across the most for "I discover" is *invenio*, so that's the one I would go with. It's also the most neutral and obvious choice, as some of the other ones could potentially mean other things.